# Stop position:fixed from zooming with user in iOS?

Tags: iphone, html, css, ios, zooming

I'm working on a tumblr theme and I'm trying to improve usability on the iPhone/iPad. The theme loads posts and organizes them horizontally. The menu is a semi-transparent position:fixed column. Here's where I'm developing the theme: http://musicforelevators.tumblr.com

The issue is that when the user zooms in to read caption text, the column fills the entire screen. Is there a way I can either redesign the column or specify that it shouldn't zoom with the user?

Does this make sense? Let me know how I can help clarify.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is it important for the user to zoom? If they want to view an image bigger they click on it. And if you zoom in the image quality won't be changed which results in blurry images. I would prevent the user from zooming. But make sure to make the font big enough for comfortable reading. As an example; in the Tumblr app you can't zoom in as well. And I don't think the users miss the option.

To disable zooming use this code in the head:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, user-scalable = no">
```